# How to extract parameter names and values using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I would like to know how to extract values of all this parameters.

**My regular expression:**

```
([\w]+)(\s*=\s*)(['|"|\w])(.+)['|"|\w]
```

**Parameter names and values that should match:**

```
name='John Doe'
name=John Doe
organization=Acme Widgets Inc.

server=192.0.2.62
port='143'
file="payroll.dat"

DOS=HIGH,UMB
DEVICE=C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS
DEVICE=C:\DOS\EMM386.EXE RAM
DEVICEHIGH=C:\DOS\ANSI.SYS
FILES=30
SHELL=C:\DOS\COMMAND.COM C:\DOS /E:512 /P
```

When i run my expression in regex101.com it only finds the first parameter that matches. In this case being: `name='John Doe'`
Desired output is  `name John Doe`

I am having extra trouble understanding how to find and extract parameter names and values without parantesis and equals signs.

Comment: You’re having trouble because it’s impossible. Regex only matches input, it doesn’t “do” anything to it, like remove chars etc. for that you need a regex and a language/tool to handle the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*['"]?([^'"\n]+)
```

The keyword will be in capture group 1 (there's no need for `[]` around `\w`).

There's no need for a capture group around the equal sign.

`[^"]?` allows an optional quote after the equal sign. There's no need to put it in a capture group.

`([^'"\n]+)` then matches everything that isn't another quote or newline. So it will capture everything until either a quote or the end of the line. This value will be put into group 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/R30GzJ/1)

Comment: Your answer works, but i can't get it to run in ubuntu terminal, where i am supposed to extract parameter names and values from a text file that contains parameters provided above.

Comment: What programming language are you using? There are many different flavors of regular expressions.

Comment: You need to use a programming language that allows you to extract the matches for capture groups.

Comment: I don't use any programming language, only the terminal.

Comment: OK, what program are you using from the terminal? `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc.?

Comment: grep, - pao and cat

Comment: You can't do this with `grep`. It just prints the entire match, it can't extract portions using capture groups. You need to use a real programming language, or not use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will useful for you:

```
/^.*?=.*?$/gm
```

I test the pattern in: https://regexr.com/

```js
var str = `
name='John Doe'
name=John Doe
organization=Acme Widgets Inc.

server=192.0.2.62
port='143'
file="payroll.dat"

DOS=HIGH,UMB
DEVICE=C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS
DEVICE=C:\DOS\EMM386.EXE RAM
DEVICEHIGH=C:\DOS\ANSI.SYS
FILES=30
SHELL=C:\DOS\COMMAND.COM C:\DOS /E:512 /P`;

console.log( str.match(/^.*?=.*?$/gm).map(str => str.replace(/("|')/g, '').replace(/=/g, ' ') ) )
```

Comment: Updated section code. I can help with any question of how implements this in JS